# firebug shows css panel beside html panel

Tags: firefox, firebug

Today, I've got a strange problem with `Firebug`. Let me explain it:

When I enable it (by `F12` key or its icon), and select `HTML` panel, I will have 2 panels.. `HTML` and `Style` (and `Layout`). But, when I go to another panel (like `Console` or `Script`) and come back to `HTML`, the side panel disappears.. and I have to disable and enable `Firebug` again to get it to work.

Is it a bug?

**Note**: I'm using firebug 1.10.3 with `FireFile` and `FireDiff` extensions. on Firefox 15.0

Comment: I have this bug too ... it also happens if i minimize firebug and restore it - the side panel with styles, layout, etc. just dissapears and i have to close firebug (f 12) and open it again.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug I too faced, the way I got over this is by re-installing Firebug.